# UserControl element inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, access-modifiers

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WinRT).

**my user control:
XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Name="LoadingProgressBarPage"
x:Class="Project1.Custom.General.UserControls.LoadingOverlayFullScreen"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Merakyahoga.com.Custom.General.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"

Foreground="{x:Null}"
d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480" >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel 
        Name="LayoutRoot_StackPanelMain"
        Grid.Row="1"
                Orientation="Vertical">
        <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" 
                     IsIndeterminate="True"
                     Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" 

                     Height="50" 
                     Width="480" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <StackPanel Name="LayoutRoot_SubStackPanel"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">

            <Image Name="ImageHolder_Main"
                   Width="54">    
            </Image>

            <TextBlock Name="ProgressBarText"
                   Text="Please Wait.." 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   FontWeight="Normal"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**cs:**

```
namespace Project1.Custom.General.UserControls
{
    public partial class LoadingOverlayFullScreen : UserControl
    {


        public LoadingOverlayFullScreen()      
        {
            InitializeComponent()

            //WINRT:
            this.LayoutRoot.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            this.LayoutRoot.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

        }

    }

}
```

**In my mainpage.cs:**

```
LoadingOverlayFullScreen LoadingOverlayFullScreenObject = new LoadingOverlayFullScreen();
        //test:
LoadingOverlayFullScreenObject.ProgressBarText = "Hello"; //ERROR Here >> **element inaccessible due to its protection level**
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By naming the `TextBlock` element, you cause the XAML compiler to generate a class member having that name, i.e. `ProgressBarText`. But the accessibility for that member is not `public`, but rather `internal`.

If you really want for the field to be `public`, you can add the `x:FieldModifier` attribute:

```
<TextBlock Name="ProgressBarText"
           x:FieldModifier="public"
           Text="Please Wait.." 
           Margin="10,0,0,0"
           FontWeight="Normal"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="18"
           Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

That said, it would be better to expose the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` object as a `string` property in your code-behind. Or even better, use data-binding to control the `Text` value of the `TextBlock` (but your code example is not complete enough for me to say how exactly you would do that).

Comment: Works for UWP (Windows 10) too.

Comment: This also works for Xamarin Forms (at least 4.8, not tested anything lower)